# DynamoDB - SpringBoot app inside Docker Containers - Application starts delayed

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, amazon-dynamodb

so I have this **docker-compose** where I have my **spring boot** application in one container and my **dynamodb** in another. Everything goes well, the containers are created and started successfully, the application starts to log stuff and then I encounter a strange **delay**. The app is completely booted only after around 3 minutes, and after those 3 minutes it just works, the DB is connected to the app.

I've tried destroying the container and I've rebuilt the images from scratch as I thought that maybe something wrecked inside the container when I forcefully closed it, but got the same result.

Below you can see the logs of the container with the app.

[image: Logs of my app]

Is there anything I am missing here ? Any other ideas to try ?

I see this weird closing connections log being logged 4 times. And I have no idea if it could be because of this.

Anyone knows what this java-sdk-http-connection-reaper is ?

> Closing connections idle longer than 60000 MILLISECONDS

If I start the application with some IntelliJ configuration it simply starts with no delay, it connects to the dynamodb container with no issues. (see the screenshot below)

[image: IntelliJ configuration logs]

Thank you! Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The delay was caused because I executed the jar with java -jar. The solution was to have the entrypoint as mvn spring-boot:run